# Defining a Set that takes in user defined type ocaml

Tags: ocaml

I have various user defined type which I need to place in a set. At the moment, I know that to define a set module, I can do something like this:

```
module Mut = Set.Make(struct type t = string ;; let compare = compare end);;
```

But is it possible to instead of string, have my own user defined type like so?:

```
module Mut = Set.Make(struct type t = procexp ;; let compare = compare end);;
```

The details of procexp is :

```
type 'ty procexp =
  Zero 
| Pproc of string
| Procdef of 'ty procexp * 'ty procexp  
| Rep of 'ty procexp
| Par of 'ty procexp * 'ty procexp 
| Concur of 'ty procexp * 'ty procexp 
| Nu of var * 'ty * 'ty procexp * pos 
| Timer of var * var* var * 'ty procexp *  'ty procexp  
| In of  var * var * 'ty * 'ty procexp * pos    
| Out of var * 'ty valexp * 'ty procexp * pos
```

Any help with this is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is yes, you can define a set containing any type for which you supply a comparison function. For many types, the built-in polymorphic comparision `compare` is suitable. Without seeing details of your type `procexp` it's hard to say more than this.

**Update**

I didn't notice that your type has a type parameter. Sorry.

This makes things more complicated. The standard Set module won't work for a parameterized type.

A simple to work it is to make a set Module for each concrete type you want. For example, you can easily make a set of `int procexp`.

Otherwise you need a way to supply the type parameter to the Set module, which (as far as I can see) means defining a functor for it.

It might look something like this:

```
# module type TYPE_PARAM = sig type u end;;
# module Mut(U: TYPE_PARAM) = Set.Make(struct type t = U.u procexp let compare = compare end);;
```

To make a set module for `int procexp` from this functor:

```
# module MutInt = Mut(struct type u = int end);;
```

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the question with the details of procexp

Comment: I'd say using `compare` is OK for this type. You have to ask yourself when you consider two values of type `procexp` to be equal, that's the essential question. Sometimes the answer is not the same as what `compare` calculates.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I will try this out.

Comment: Is it too much ask if I could get some sample code on how to define this? I tried it out and I keep getting an error:

Unbound type parameter 'ty
I am unable to figure this out because 'ty procexp is the name of this user defined type. I am quite new to Ocaml so I am struggling with this

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the type parameter. My mistake.

Comment: Does this mean that it wont be possible to define this Set?

Comment: You can have a set for any particular concrete type (with all parameters specified). You can't have a set of a type with an unspecified parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I will try out this functor and update based on what works.

Comment: I am a bit confused with this: module MutInt = Mut(struct type u = int end);;
Does it mean that I have to create a set module for each type i.e int, string etc? What if I have to add an entire "procexp" to the set?

Comment: You can readily make a set of any concrete `'a procexp` type. Example for `string procexp`: `module M = Set.Make(struct type t = string procexp let compare = compare end)`.  If you use the functor I sketched, it just makes it slightly easier.